# Creating a Time Dimension table with Intervals in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

What is the easiest way to create a table in oracle to get the output as shown below;

| Time Key | 5 Minute Interval | 10 Minute Interval | 15 Minute Interval |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 12:00:00 | 12:10:00 | 12:15:00 |
| 101 | 12:05:00 | 12:10:00 | 12:15:00 |
| 102 | 12:10:00 | 12:20:00 | 12:15:00 |
| 103 | 12:15:00 | 12:20:00 | 12:30:00 |

The hours will be displayed in 24 hour format and will be used to join the time key onto a fact table to be loaded into a Microsoft Analysis Tabular Model.

Comment: Can you explain the logic? Why does the time key start from 100, and not from 0 (or 1)? If the 5 minute interval starts at 12:00 (not at 12:05), why does the 10 minute interval start at 12:10, and the 15 minute interval at 12:15? Why don't they also start at 12:00? Etc. Don't ask us to guess; three of us will come back with eight different guesses. Explain exactly what you want the output to be (that is: the logic for deriving it).

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you need a *row generator*. Here's an example.

Date format (just to know what you're looking at):

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.
```

Query (creates 10 rows of data; change value in line #9 for more (or less) rows):

```
SQL> with temp (time_key, datum) as
  2    (select 99, trunc(sysdate) datum from dual)
  3  select
  4    time_key + level time_key,
  5    datum + ( 5 * (level - 1)) / (24 * 60) five_min,
  6    datum + (10 * (level - 1)) / (24 * 60) ten_min,
  7    datum + (15 * (level - 1)) / (24 * 60) fifteen_min
  8  from temp
  9  connect by level <= 10;

  TIME_KEY FIVE_MIN            TEN_MIN             FIFTEEN_MIN
---------- ------------------- ------------------- -------------------
       100 04.01.2021 00:00:00 04.01.2021 00:00:00 04.01.2021 00:00:00
       101 04.01.2021 00:05:00 04.01.2021 00:10:00 04.01.2021 00:15:00
       102 04.01.2021 00:10:00 04.01.2021 00:20:00 04.01.2021 00:30:00
       103 04.01.2021 00:15:00 04.01.2021 00:30:00 04.01.2021 00:45:00
       104 04.01.2021 00:20:00 04.01.2021 00:40:00 04.01.2021 01:00:00
       105 04.01.2021 00:25:00 04.01.2021 00:50:00 04.01.2021 01:15:00
       106 04.01.2021 00:30:00 04.01.2021 01:00:00 04.01.2021 01:30:00
       107 04.01.2021 00:35:00 04.01.2021 01:10:00 04.01.2021 01:45:00
       108 04.01.2021 00:40:00 04.01.2021 01:20:00 04.01.2021 02:00:00
       109 04.01.2021 00:45:00 04.01.2021 01:30:00 04.01.2021 02:15:00

10 rows selected.

SQL>
```

In Oracle, there's no "time" datatype. We use `date` and it consists of both date AND time. Your example shows that you want time only; well, you can't have it, not as a `date` datatype. You can use e.g. `TO_CHAR` function on it (and fetch only time component). I wouldn't recommend you to store those values as strings into `varchar2` datatype column as nothing prevents you (or someone else) to put e.g. 12:3f:75 into it, and that certainly isn't valid time value.

So, you'd then:

```
SQL> create table test as
  2  with temp (time_key, datum) as
  3    (select 99, trunc(sysdate) datum from dual)
  4  select
  5    time_key + level time_key,
  6    datum + ( 5 * (level - 1)) / (24 * 60) five_min,
  7    datum + (10 * (level - 1)) / (24 * 60) ten_min,
  8    datum + (15 * (level - 1)) / (24 * 60) fifteen_min
  9  from temp
 10  connect by level <= 10;

Table created.

SQL> select time_key,
  2    to_char(five_min, 'hh24:mi:ss') five_min
  3  from test;

  TIME_KEY FIVE_MIN
---------- --------
       100 00:00:00
       101 00:05:00
       102 00:10:00
       103 00:15:00
       104 00:20:00
       105 00:25:00
       106 00:30:00
       107 00:35:00
       108 00:40:00
       109 00:45:00

10 rows selected.

SQL>
```

---

To answer question T. Peter posted as a comment: I don't know for other databases, but - principle that should work elsewhere is to use a cross join (Cartesian product) with a subquery that returns "a lot of rows". In Oracle, `ALL_OBJECTS` is such a table. It isn't *indefinite*; in my sample schema, it contains ~8000 rows. For example (see lines #8 - 10):

```
SQL> with temp (time_key, datum) as
  2    (select 99, trunc(sysdate) datum from dual)
  3  select
  4    time_key + rn time_key,
  5    datum + ( 5 * (rn - 1)) / (24 * 60) five_min,
  6    datum + (10 * (rn - 1)) / (24 * 60) ten_min,
  7    datum + (15 * (rn - 1)) / (24 * 60) fifteen_min
  8  from temp cross join (select rownum rn
  9                        from all_tables
 10                        where rownum <= 10
 11                       );

  TIME_KEY FIVE_MIN            TEN_MIN             FIFTEEN_MIN
---------- ------------------- ------------------- -------------------
       100 04.01.2021 00:00:00 04.01.2021 00:00:00 04.01.2021 00:00:00
       101 04.01.2021 00:05:00 04.01.2021 00:10:00 04.01.2021 00:15:00
       <snip>
```

Basically, keyword here is "row generator". I suggest you Google for it and add database name you use.

Comment: this is wonderful, `connect by` is such a great thing oracle have. but since other dbms doesn't have this function, can this be reproduce by using cte or other way around?

Comment: I added some more info by editing the answer. Have a look, @T.Peter

Comment: thank for the reply, this help me a lot. I am working on many different dbms but the general idea is really viable on most of them :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive sub-query factoring clause and get the time values using `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` data type:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( time_key, five_minute, ten_minute, fifteen_minute ) AS
WITH data ( time_key, five_minute, ten_minute, fifteen_minute, num_rows ) AS (
  SELECT 100,
         INTERVAL '12:00' HOUR TO MINUTE,
         INTERVAL '12:00' HOUR TO MINUTE,
         INTERVAL '12:00' HOUR TO MINUTE,
         4
  FROM   DUAL
UNION ALL
  SELECT time_key + 1,
         five_minute    + INTERVAL '5' MINUTE,
         ten_minute     + INTERVAL '10' MINUTE,
         fifteen_minute + INTERVAL '15' MINUTE,
         num_rows - 1
  FROM   data
  WHERE  num_rows > 1
)
SELECT time_key,
       five_minute,
       ten_minute,
       fifteen_minute
FROM   data;
```

Then the table contains:

> ```
> TIME_KEY | FIVE_MINUTE                   | TEN_MINUTE                    | FIFTEEN_MINUTE               
> -------: | :---------------------------- | :---------------------------- | :----------------------------
>      100 | +000000000 12:00:00.000000000 | +000000000 12:00:00.000000000 | +000000000 12:00:00.000000000
>      101 | +000000000 12:05:00.000000000 | +000000000 12:10:00.000000000 | +000000000 12:15:00.000000000
>      102 | +000000000 12:10:00.000000000 | +000000000 12:20:00.000000000 | +000000000 12:30:00.000000000
>      103 | +000000000 12:15:00.000000000 | +000000000 12:30:00.000000000 | +000000000 12:45:00.000000000
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0e1daf8687ea01c8cd1fe3cc1c1be1f7)*